# What is the correct way to handle HTTP response in React Native component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am building a mobile app and I'm using Django REST Framework as a backend. And I am also using Redux. One of the API that I am using is to validate an OTP code. If the OTP code is matched, then I am retuning with the response from the server if this is a new user or not. If it's a new user then I'll redirect it to a registration screen, if not then I'll redirect it to the login screen, this is my problem.

I am storing the response of the server in variable named isNewUser in redux store. Then, I am accessing it Inside my component with useSelector. When I click on the button after I entered then OTP code, I dispatch two actions. First the one to validate the OTP. The second is either will be a dispatch for Login or dispatch for registration action, this is depends on the variable isNewUser which I am getting from redux store.

The problem is that, when I dispatch the first action, which is validation of the OTP and storing of the isNewUser variable, the value of this variable is not updated in my component until the next render, so I can't dispatch the second action until I click the button again so that the value of the variable is updated.

So how to fix that? I don't know if my implementation is correct or not or there is a better one.

Here is my code for the action, I didn't write the code for login and register actions yet

```
export const validateOTP = (otp, mobileNum) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/validate_otp", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        otp: otp,
        mobile: mobileNum
      })
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorResData = await response.json();
      console.log(errorResData);
    }

    const resData = await response.json();
    if (resData.status === false) {
      throw new Error(resData.detail);
    } else {
      const isNewUser = resData.isNewUser;
      dispatch({
        type: VALIDATE_OTP,
        isNewUser: isNewUser
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Here is my code for the reducer:

```
import { VALIDATE_OTP } from "../actions/auth";

const initialState = {
  isNewUser: null
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case VALIDATE_OTP: {
      const isNewUserVal = action.isNewUser;
      return {
        ...state,
        isNewUser: isNewUserVal
      };
    }
  }
  return state;
};
```

Here is a sample code from the React Native component:

```
const CodeEntryScreen = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isNewUser = useSelector(state => state.auth.isNewUser)
  const [error, setError] = useState();


  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      Alert.alert("An Error Occurred", error, [{ text: "Okay" }]);
    }
  }, [error]);

  const validateOTPHandler = async () => {
    setError(null);
    try {
      await dispatch(authActions.validateOTP(otp, mobileNum));
      console.log(isNewUser)
     if(isNewUser) {
        // dispatch resgister action
      }
      else {
        // dispatch  login action 
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this issue with little modifications. The easier one is this:

## 1) Use `dispatch` return value in your `validateOTPHandler`

In your `validateOTP` function, you have this at the end:

```js
dispatch({
  type: VALIDATE_OTP,
  isNewUser: isNewUser
});
```

Make your function to return that instead:

```js
return dispatch({
  type: VALIDATE_OTP,
  isNewUser: isNewUser
});
```

With that change, in your component, you can access to the payload of your action this way:

```js
  const validateOTPHandler = async () => {
    setError(null);
    try {
      const { isNewUser: isNew } = await dispatch(authActions.validateOTP(otp, mobileNum));
      console.log(isNew)
     if(isNew) {
        // dispatch resgister action
      }
      else {
        // dispatch  login action 
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
  };
```

That is the easier change to make it work as you want.

## 2) `useEffect`

I think this is more similar to the flow you had in mind:

- Valide the code (update the store)
- Re-render: you got the new value
- Now do something: login or register

But do that, you need to use `useEffect` in order to listen the changes you made this way:

```js
const CodeEntryScreen = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isNewUser = useSelector(state => state.auth.isNewUser)
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false); // true when validateOTP succeeds

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      Alert.alert("An Error Occurred", error, [{ text: "Okay" }]);
    }
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      // validateOTP succeed... let's check isNewUser :)
      if (isNewUser) {
        // dispatch register
      } else {
        // dispatch login
      }
    }
  }, [success, isNewUser]);

  const validateOTPHandler = async () => {
    setError(null);
    setSuccess(false);
    try {
      await dispatch(authActions.validateOTP(otp, mobileNum));
      setSuccess(true);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
  };
```